# Distance Function Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I'm trying to search on a table using full-text search but i need to be able to search similar words, so for example: if i have an entry in the database "masr el gadeeda" and i search for "misr el gedeeda" or "masr el gedeeda" or "masr al gadeeda", i get the "masr el gadeeda" entry, does full text search provide such capabilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example may can help you.

F. Using CONTAINS with

The following example searches for all products with words of the form ride: riding, ridden, and so on.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT Description
FROM Production.ProductDescription
WHERE CONTAINS(Description, ' FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL, ride) ');
GO
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx